# Angular TinyMCE icons disappeared

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular8

I have an Angular 8 project with tinymce editor. It works locally, but at some point toolbar icons disappeared in production deployed using CI/CD pipeline.

[image: screenshor]

I'm getting 404 for `/tinymce/icons/default/icons.min.js`.

**What the heck is icons.min.js??**

My angular.json assets looks like this:

```
{
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins",
                "output": "/tinymce/skins/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes",
                "output": "/tinymce/themes/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins",
                "output": "/tinymce/plugins/"
              }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TinyMCE 5 contains an `icons` folder with two JavaScript files.  It would appear that you have not included that content in what you deployed to production.

Based on your example json you likely need to add something like this:

```
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "node_modules/tinymce/icons",
  "output": "/tinymce/icons/"
},
```

Comment: This solution works for me. I got the error when I upgraded from TinyMCE 5.2.2 to 5.4.1, tinymce-angular 3.5.1 to 4.0.0 and Angular 9.1.6 to 10.0.3 I would say the separate icons  glob must hab been added somwhere between those TinyMCE versions.

Answer (score 0):

tinymce.init({
selector: '#editor',
**icons: false,**

Answer (score 0):

Latest integration [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#tinymceangularintegrationquickstartguide) provides one line to load all tinyMCE assets. It is successful on `Angular 9 LTS` and `tinyMCE` latest version of `v5`.

```
"assets": [
   { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce", "output": "/tinymce/" }
 ]
```